# How can verify the type of an input variable in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, variables, types

When i get a value by input, i wanna check what kind of value is for control it:

```java
int age = input.next();
book.setAge(age);

if (age....) { // i wanna check if "age" in input it's a String or other
    type ...
}
```

Comment: You can use hasNextInt() method

Comment: Use `try/catch` and `Integer.parseInt`. You can also use the regex, `[\d_]+` to check if a string is parseable to an integer.

Comment: Scanner#next() inputs a String. You code should show a compiler error because age is an int. Age cannot reference a String.